# Am I supposed to dispose redirected StandardOutput/StandardError

Tags: .net, process

If I redirect `StandardOutput`/`StandardError` when creating a `Process` object, should I dispose the `StreamReaders` when I no longer need the `Process` object?  Using reflector I see that `Process.Dispose()` does not do this for me (unless I'm missing something).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes the process object disposes of its own readers and their underlying streams. Redirected output retrieves a reader instance but the underlying stream is still managed by the processinfo which gets disposed automatically so no, you don't need to dispose of the reader.

Comment: @Teoman - I'm a bit confused, my class did not instantiate the readers.  Redirecting standard output/input is an option in ProcessStartInfo class.  If I set ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true and use that ProcessStartInfo to start a process, then Process object automagically creates the StreamReaders for me.

Comment: SFun28, just made a little test and updated the answer. Turns out, disposing of the reader is unnecessary since it actually disposes of the underlying stream. With the redirected output, you're already reading the redirected internal stream which gets closed automatically along with process.

Comment: cool!  And could you clarify what the "processinfo" is?  Do you mean the Process object?

Comment: Yes process object, sorry for being vague.